# Java IDE: Eclipse and NetBeans annoyances : any possible fixes or alternatives?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, ide

I like the Eclipse IDE, but it has an annoying bug that makes it too frustrating, where I will be typing a line of text, and after the carriage return or scrolling, the IDE draws the line incorrectly or overlaps itself, making it impossible for me to decipher it without scrolling back up to erase the line and let it refresh itself.

Both NetBeans and Eclipse have a problem where the context help will only appear after a '.' is entered after an identifier while I'm typing. After any incorrect letters have been entered or a symbol or space is typed, the context help will disappear and not return until I erase all the way back to the point and retype it.

Is there any way to fix these problems? They are very annoying to me. If not, are there any better IDEs available?

EDIT: Eclipse release was Europa; upgrading to Helios release solved everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In eclipse check out

`Windows` ->
`Preferences` ->
`Java` ->
`Editor` ->
`Content Assist`

In there are some options for `Auto-Activation` that you can tweak, and yes... putting every character on your keyboard into the `Auto activation triggers for Java` option will do pretty much what VS does.

Thanks for asking this question cause it lead me to try this! :D

Comment: I will have to try that, too. The only IDE that I have seen that does this is MSDEV2010; and it grew on me. Now I'm pampered by it.

Comment: One other thing to note is that the characters are case sensitive, so if you want both lower case and upper case letters to trigger auto assist you'll need both in the box.

Comment: How are you inserting more than one character into the auto-activation fields? It only allows me to set 3 or 4.

Comment: @TurtleToes - No tricks, just put the cursor in it and hit all the character keys, what version of Eclipse are you running, I'm on Helios Service Pack 1 (1.3.1.20100916-1202)

Comment: I'm downloading Eclipse Helios SR2 now to test it out, perhaps this will answer my other prayers, as well.

Comment: Wow; this is much better. I wasn't aware there were different releases of Eclipse. Apparently the one I had is not as good as this one. The line drawing bug is also not present in the Helios release. Gotta check this one. Thanks a bunch

Comment: @TurtleToes - Sorry I'm actually 3.6.1, let me see if 3.3.2 is different in this regard.

Comment: @TurtleToes - Upgrading is even easier than me researching! Glad you like it! and thanks for the accept.

Comment: The release I just replaced was Eclipse Europa? Good thing this was hashed out because I really like Eclipse and these new features are going to help out a lot, and living without that bug will save a lot of hair pulling

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try IntelliJ IDEA 10.

Answer (score 2):

Never had the line drawing issue.

In Eclipse, the auto-complete / context menu can always be brought back up, at any time, by hitting `ctrl+space`

Comment: Netbeans also has the same shortcut to bring up the auto-complete.

Comment: @RiaanCornelius: Not surprising, since they both stole it from Visual Studio.

Comment: Eclipse also has customization for just about anything you could want... don't write it off so easily!

Comment: Hmmm, I agree, Eclipse is a good IDE. If it weren't for the bug I would keep using it. I have searched all the settings for ways of fixing the bug, but I can't find anything, and I can't find occurrences of it happening to anyone else. I may have to switch to NetBeans. IntelliJ is having major problems right away and has a strange interface to me.